# MYSQL Inner Join Two Tables Same Column name Different Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like this:-

```
Tablea
-------
id|Comp_name|
1 |abc  |

Tableb
--------
ids|id|Comp_name|
2  |1 |def|
```

I'm trying to inner join these two table into one with query like this

```
SELECT * FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id
```

The result is like this

```
id|Comp_name|ids|Comp_name|
1 |abc      |2  |def|
```

.
How To separate Comp_name value into php ?
I tried code like this but fail:-

```
foreach($query->result() as $row){
echo '<tr class="'.$class.'">
         <td>
            '.$row->Tablea.Comp_name.'
         </td>
         <td>
            '.$row->Tablea.Comp_name.'
         </td>
```

Comment: try using alias

Comment: @1000111 where should I put the alias ?

Comment: `SELECT tablea.id,tablea.Comp_name as comp_name1 FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id`

Comment: @Anant I want outcome like this <td>abc</td>  <td> def</td>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name.

For more info [Click](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html) here.

SQL Query looks like

```
SELECT tablea.id,tablea.Comp_name AS compname_a, tableb.* 
FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id
```

PHP

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row):?>

<tr class="<?php echo $class?>">
    <td><?php echo $row->compname_a ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row->Comp_name ?></td>
</tr>   

<?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your desired output, you just need to use [`alias`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html) for getting same column name value from two tables.

**Modified Query:**

```
SELECT tablea.id, tablea.Comp_name as FirstVal, 
tableb.ids, tableb.Comp_name as SecondVal
FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id
```

Than you can get in php something like:

```
$row->FirstVal // for ist value
$row->SecondVal // for second value
```

*You can also explore more:* [MYSQL Alias](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/alias.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
SELECT id, tablea.Comp_name as A_Comp_name, ids, tableb.Comp_name as B_Comp_name 
FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id
```

And the result will be something like this:

```
id|A_Comp_name|ids|B_Comp_name|
1 |abc        |2  |def        |
```

Answer (score 0):

Use alias for this type of situation.
query:

```
SELECT tablea.Comp_name as company1, tableb.Comp_name as company2
FROM tablea 
INNER JOIN tableb ON tablea.id=tableb.id
```